# Indicated quantities for the given group homomorphism

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, group-homomorphism

I was exercising for group theory trying to find the indicated quantities for the given homomorphisms. What I am struggling to understand is to find the quantities when it comes to homomorphism from a group product to a group or another group product. Here's the example

Find $Ker(\alpha)$ and $\alpha(-3,2) $ for the homomorphism $\mathbb{Z}$ x $\mathbb{Z} \to \mathbb{Z}$ where $\alpha(1,0) = 3$ and $\alpha(0,1) = -5$

To find $\alpha(-3,2)$ I tried doing $$ \alpha(-3,2) = -3\alpha(1,0)+2\alpha(0,1) = -3*3 + 2*(-5) = -19$$
and for $Ker(\alpha)$ I tried $$ \alpha(a,b) = 0 \implies a\alpha(1,0)+b\alpha(0,1) = 3*a - 5*b = 0$$

So what is Ker now? Maybe some help or suggestions to tackle these type of problems differently would be huge for me.

Thank you and be safe.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can write what you currently have as
$$\ker(\alpha) = \{(a, b) \in \mathbb Z \times \mathbb Z: 3a - 5b = 0\}.$$

As it turns out, all solutions to this equation are of the form $(5n, 3n)$ for $n \in \mathbb Z$. You can look up the phrase *homogeneous linear Diophantine equation* like [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Diophantine_equation#Linear_Diophantine_equations) to get more information on why (or just convince yourself that all of these tuples are solutions). However, these number theory details are disjoint from the group-theoretic questions about homomorphisms that you're asking.

As for this kind of problem in general: the key is that you knew the value of $\alpha$ on a $\mathbb Z$-basis $\{(1, 0), (0, 1)\}$ for $\mathbb Z \times \mathbb Z$. You can then use the homomorphism property to determine $\alpha(a, b)$ for all other $(a, b)$. It's analogous to how in linear algebra we encode homomorphisms (there called *linear transformations*) by matrices, and matrices are keeping track of where the basis goes. In this case, we'd write
$$\alpha = \begin{pmatrix} 3 & -5 \end{pmatrix}. $$

Comment: thank you so much for your help sir.